# Both splat and keyword args in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I have a method in a Ruby 2.0 script with the following signature:

```
def method(*args, **kwargs)
```

This script fails to run in Ruby 1.9 because the `**` syntax is new. Is there a way to change the method signature while preserving the Ruby 2.0 behavior? Ideally, I would like to not modify the callers.

Note that there are methods in the Ruby core in 1.9 that accept both a variable number of arguments and additional options, e.g., `Kernel#system`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close to the same behavior, although you'll have to access the `kwargs` via keys:

```
def method(*args)
  kwargs = case args.last
  when Hash then args.pop
  else {}
  end
  # stuff here
  # puts args
  # puts kwargs
end
```

Comment: Works well! Thanks. I've replaced it by `if args.last.is_a?(Hash) then args.pop else {} end`. Other than this cosmetic change, I like the solution.